# Crop thumbnail in imagemagick - specify center at X, Y position

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick, thumbnails

I would like to generate thumbnails for my website. Now I am using the following to process folder (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261855/recommendation-for-compressing-jpg-files-with-imagemagick) answer):

```
mogrify -interlace Plane -thumbnail 280x210^ 
-gravity center -extent 280x210 -quality 85% *.jpg
```

This will create thumbnails with given size (resize and crop).

I also have single image version of this command:

```
convert test.jpg -interlace Plane -thumbnail 280x210^ 
 -gravity center -extent 280x210 -quality 85%  testout.jpg
```

I'm also using [facedetect](http://www.thregr.org/~wavexx/hacks/facedetect/) to get positions of faces from the original image (before creating thumbnails). For photos with faces I have calculated average X, Y position of faces center.

Now, I would like to use this position in the command above to crop pictures smarter. Currently image is cropped from both sides (`-gravity center`), but I would like to use my coordinates so faces are displayed when image is cropped.

Is there a way how I can feed this into imagemagick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `-shave` to remove part of the image, so that the face moves to the center, then apply your original command.