# How to resize images using terminal on Mac OSX?

Tags: image, macos, terminal

I need a simple and free way to resize images and do batch jobs, if necessary. Free image manipulation software has been trickier to use than it should be.

Answer (score 278, accepted):

The following command will do this very easily:

```
sips -Z 640 *.jpg
```

[Lifehacker](https://lifehacker.com/batch-resize-images-quickly-in-the-os-x-terminal-5962420) explains:

> `sips` is the command being used and -Z tells it to maintain the image's aspect ratio. "640" is the maximum height and width to be used and "*.jpg" instructs your computer to downsize every image ending in .jpg. It's really simple and shrinks your images very quickly. **Be sure to make a copy first if you want to preserve their larger size as well**.

Here is an example where we preserve the originals and send the resized images to a subdirectory called `resized`:

```
mkdir -p resized && sips -Z 640 *.jpg --out resized/
```

Comment: I get a `Error: Cannot do --extractTag on file error` when trying to convert a png on High Sierra :-(

Comment: add --out parameter to make it produces rather than directly modifies the input file

Comment: One issue is that it will still resample the image even if it is smaller than the size you specify. So it can increase the filesize of many images if you target them all. I wish it would just ignore the file if it was smaller.

Comment: @ggedde you may want to turn to Imagick. It has Never enlarge flag https://imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#shrink And here is a useful example of Imagick in the comment section https://stackoverflow.com/a/44208640/3733214

Comment: plus one to imagemagick, the image quality is better when resized down in comparison to sips.

Answer (score 32):

[imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) helps:

```
$ convert foo.jpg -resize 50% bar.jpg
```

There are a lot more things it can do, including the conversion between formats, applying effects, crop, colorize and much, much more.

Comment: convert: no decode delegate for this image format `PNG'

Comment: @AlexeySh. You're missing a delegate for PNG, try installing it from [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/delegates/)

Comment: Winner, note I simply installed this with `homebrew install imagemagick`

Comment: Or if using anaconda: `conda install -c conda-forge imagemagick`

Answer (score 13):

Here is script that uses `sips` to recursively resize all the images in a given folder (and its sub-folders), and places the resized images in a `resized` folder on the same tree level as the image: https://gist.github.com/lopespm/893f323a04fcc59466d7

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script resizes all the images it finds in a folder (and its subfolders) and resizes them
# The resized image is placed in the /resized folder which will reside in the same directory as the image
#
# Usage: > ./batch_resize.sh

initial_folder="/your/images/folder" # You can use "." to target the folder in which you are running the script for example
resized_folder_name="resized"

all_images=$(find -E $initial_folder -iregex ".*\.(jpg|gif|png|jpeg)")

while read -r image_full_path; do
    filename=$(basename "$image_full_path");
    source_folder=$(dirname "$image_full_path");
    destination_folder=$source_folder"/"$resized_folder_name"/";
    destination_full_path=$destination_folder$filename;

    if [ ! -z "$image_full_path" -a "$image_full_path" != " " ] &&
        # Do not resize images inside a folder that was already resized
        [ "$(basename "$source_folder")" != "$resized_folder_name" ]; then 

        mkdir "$destination_folder";
        sips -Z 700 "$image_full_path" --out "$destination_full_path";

    fi

done <<< "$all_images"
```

Comment: Before running script you should run "chmod +x batch_resize.sh" to make script executable. I replaced 700 to 400 and it resized 3000 images in folder less than 3 minutes. Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you should be able to execute this with a command for the pixel size limit instead of having to hard-code it into the script...

Answer (score 10):

Previous answers are correct, you can use mogrify too. For example, if you want to reduce the size of many images in  a directory by 60% then you can use the command below:

*of course always make a backup of your images in to another directory before playing with this command.*

```
mogrify -resize 60% *
```

Answer (score 9):

magic trick for itunesconnect :)

```
mkdir ./iPhone5-5-Portrait
sips -z 2208 1242 *.jpg -s formatOptions 70 --out ./iPhone5-5-Portrait
sips -z 2208 1242 *.png --out ./iPhone5-5-Portrait
```

Answer (score 8):

Additionally of @grepit reply

The correct syntax is:

```
magick mogrify -resize 60% *
```

And you need to install [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php), the easiest way is using homebrew:

```
brew install imagemagick
```

Answer (score 3):

Many people here have mentioned imagick, but it's not enough (and fast) for me, especially when I want to reduce only the image whose width/height is larger than a dimention, and leave all others smaller.

Install imagemagick,

```bash
brew install imagemagick
```

All examples are given in [the official site](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/). For resizing images, check [this section](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/).

An example of resizing all images in the current folder (only for images with dimension(s) **larger** than 1280x1080) and outputting them to an existing "out" folder,

```bash
magick mogrify -path out -resize 1280x1080\> *
```

Other useful options for `-resize` (copied from [the official site](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php)),

| size | General description (actual behavior can vary for different options and settings) |
| --- | --- |
| scale% | Height and width both scaled by specified percentage. |
| scale-x%xscale-y% | Height and width individually scaled by specified percentages. (Only one % symbol needed.) |
| width | Width given, height automagically selected to preserve aspect ratio. |
| xheight | Height given, width automagically selected to preserve aspect ratio. |
| widthxheight | Maximum values of height and width given, aspect ratio preserved. |
| widthxheight^ | Minimum values of width and height given, aspect ratio preserved. |
| widthxheight! | Width and height emphatically given, original aspect ratio ignored. |
| widthxheight> | Shrinks an image with dimension(s) larger than the corresponding width and/or height argument(s). |
| widthxheight< | Enlarges an image with dimension(s) smaller than the corresponding width and/or height argument(s). |
| area@ | Resize image to have specified area in pixels. Aspect ratio is preserved. |
| x:y | Here x and y denotes an aspect ratio (e.g. 3:2 = 1.5). |
| x:y^ | remove rows or columns to achieve the given aspect ratio. |
| x:y# | add rows or columns to achieve the given aspect ratio. |
| {size}{offset} | Specifying the offset (default is +0+0). Below, {size} refers to any of the forms above. |
| {size}{+-}x{+-}y | Horizontal and vertical offsets x and y, specified in pixels. Signs are required for both. Offsets are affected by -gravity setting. Offsets are not affected by % or other size operators. Note that positive X and Y offsets are in the inward direction towards the center of the image for all -gravity options, except 'center'. For East, +X is left. For South, +Y is up. For SouthEast, +X is left and +Y is up. For center, the normal X and Y directional convention is used (+X is right and +Y is down). |